# If I call a static method, does the constructor run

Tags: java, constructor, static, scope, static-methods

I have a class called `Tile` with a static method `public static BufferedImage grass()` and inside the class is also a constructor `public Tile()` which sets a variable.

So what I'm wondering is if I call the `grass()` method from another class `Tile.grass()`, will the constructor run?

I'm assuming not as my `grass()` method is returning `null`.

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Tile {

    public static final int size = 50;

    private static BufferedImage mapSprites;

    public Tile(){
        try{
            Tile.setMapSprites(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("res/mas.png")));
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static BufferedImage grass(){
        return getMapSprites().getSubimage(0, 0, 10, 10);;
    }

    private static BufferedImage getMapSprites() {
        return mapSprites;
    }

    private static void setMapSprites(BufferedImage mapSprites) {
        Tile.mapSprites = mapSprites;
    }
}
```

I could create a function the gets the `mapSprite` for every tile I return. But I don't think that would be very efficient. Is there another solution?

(Just for reference here is how I am calling it in my `Map` class)

```
public void render(){
    g.drawImage(Tile.grass(), 0, 0, null);
}
```

Comment: How about testing it? Put a breakpoint in the constructor and see. Or a System.out.println("hello from constructor");

Comment: No, it won't. It's a static method and it doesn't construct an instance.

Comment: @JBNizet - the only correct answer

Comment: Right, so my only solution is to set mapSprites everytime I call a tile method?

Comment: @DominicSore Or use a static initialization block.

Comment: I'm failing to see why this is downvoted.

Comment: It's downvoted because a simple stupid test would have given you the answer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No, the constructor doesn't run if you only call a static method of a class.  There is no instance of a class associated with a call to a static method.  That is why `mapSprites` is `null`.

To populate `mapSprites`, you can move the code that initializes it out of the constructor and into a static initializer.  This way, it will run the first time the class is referenced, so that `mapSprites` is initialized properly when you call a `static` method for the first time.

```
static {
    try{
        Tile.setMapSprites(ImageIO.read(Tile.class.getResource("res/mas.png")));
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

With static initializers, you must be careful to avoid having any exception propagate out of it.  If it does, then it will be wrapped in an `ExceptionInInitializerError` that will be throw and that will be bad news for your program.

You may also want to make the (now useless) constructor `private`, to prevent instantiation of the class, because your class is now a utility class, where everything is `static`, and an instance of this class is now useless.

Comment: @Clashsoft You're right.  I changed it to `Tile.class`.

Answer (score 3):

No.  It won't.  The constructor will execute the first time (and every time) something creates a `new` instance of Tile.

If you have some code you want to run once, when the class (not the 
instance) is initialize, you can put it in a static block:

```
private static BufferedImage mapSprites;
static {
    try{
        Tile.setMapSprites(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("res/mas.png")));
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

An alternative would be to make your class a [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern.).

Answer (score 0):

You can put the image initialization code inside a `static` initializer block, because it is shared between all `Tile` instances.

```
static {
    try {
        Tile.setMapSprites(ImageIO.read(Tile.class.getResource("res/mas.png")));
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

That way you don't have to load the image every time you create a new `Tile` instance.

Concerning your original question, the constructor will only be called if you explicitly use the `new` operator, as in `new Tile()`.